# Parallel Aggregate Collection

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, aggregate, parallel.foreach

I have seen code for parallel aggregation for basic types, e.g.

```
Parallel.For<int>(0, result.Count, () => 0, (i, loop, subtotal) =>
    {
        subtotal += result[i];
        return subtotal;
    },
    (x) => Interlocked.Add(ref sum, x)
);
```

I was wondering if there was an equivalent for a list/other collection e.g:

```
List<Result> AllResults;
Parallel.ForEach(allIDs, (currentID) =>
{

    subList.add(GetResultFor(currentID));
    return subList;
},
(x) =>
{
    lock(AllResults)
        AllResults.AddRange(subList);
};
```

I am guessing there is nothing that nice and neat but I can't think of another way of doing it, certainly not through a standard parralel.ForEach because I cant think of how you would say "this core have this range, this core this range"....

Comment: That first code block is almost certainly slower than not using Parallel at all.

Comment: Why do you say that? perhaps I have not shown a reasonable psudo code. I picture it as each thread get its own "range" to process, not each one returns a list of 1

Comment: this is almost always a horrible idea performance wise. and even worse debuging race conditions wise.

Comment: Can someone explain why? The expensive part is in the "getresultfor" and they can run independently so I want to run those in parrallel, but I need the end result to all be stored in the same list. So how should it be done? @AK_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think in both examples, [*PLINQ*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx) can serve you better and without any need to manually lock while using non thread-safe collections.

Your sum calculation can be converted to:

```
var sum = result.AsParallel().Sum();
```

And you second example with the `List<T>` can be converted to:

```
List<Result> results = allIDs.AsParallel()
                             .Select(id => GetResultFor(id))
                             .ToList();
```

Note parallelism is only as good as what tests say. Not always will going parallel speed up your code, there are times where it may even degrade performance against a sequential loop.

Comment: "might". It depends on exactly how `ToList` and `Sum` work... **Generally speaking**  calling `ToList` means you wait until the expression finishes evaluating right there and then. Leaving it out means PLINQ can decide to do the evaluation and summing simultaneously... This might be pretty significant in more complex scenarios...

Comment: @AK_ The materialization of the query will give you the same performance as you'd see if you used deffered execution and later iterate it. What you might be seeing, if the collection is large enough, is your system consuming more memory then it would if it lazily went through. The *performance* of the query itself will be based on the underlying source, and how long `GetResultFor` will actually take, since we're only projecting elements here, nothing more.

Comment: Also... calling `ToList` ends all the LINQ "magic" so it's better to do it as late as possible, or avoid altogether.

Comment: @AK_ What LINQ magic? You mean deferring the execution? There's nothing magical about that, and theres no reason to avoid it if what you need is the entire underlying collection to be processed at the time of the method call. *It's better to do it as late as possible* Says who? What happens if between the creation of the query and the processing the underlying collection changes?

Comment: @AK_ If I were you, I would avoid handing out bad counsel with no proper explanation.

Comment: If I were you I would try to avoid being so arrogant and so wrong both at the same time.

Comment: @AK_ This has nothing to do with arrogance. This is simply me trying to understand why you're telling people that calling `ToList` might degrade performance further, which is ambiguous comment that doesn't tell the story behind your train of thought. The only thing `ToList` will do is materialize the query. That may or may not be a desired behavior for the OP, but you don't know that, since we don't really know what the OP is planning to do with this code. So saying something *general* as you did may lead people to think wrongly of an operation. Think about that.

Comment: This isn't the place nor the format for this discussion...
1. What I'm saying is that in a general map-reduce algorithm (not necessarily googles), If applicable, the entire algorithm should run faster if the map and the reduce run simultaneously. Specifically summation can also be broken into small parts and run in parallel.  
2. By "LINQ magic" I didn't mean differing. I meant the abbility of linq to treat the query as a chain of function compositions, and making smart decisions about its execution. Also If your source isn't immutable it's breaking functional programming rules...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94695/discussion-between-yuval-itzchakov-and-ak).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thank you, I have been able to half the time it takes for my processing using this approach. I had no difference between using "tolist" and not using "tolist" as the only thing I do with the resulting query is cycle through it. I am currently trying to see if I could speed it up further.

Comment: @chrispepper1989 Great! glad it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Result> AllResults = new List<Result>();

Parallel.ForEach(allIDs, () => new List<Result>(), (id, loopState, subList) =>
{
   subList.Add(GetResultFor(id));
   return subList;
},
subList => 
{ 
     lock(AllResults)
         AllResults.AddRange(subList); 
});
```

Comment: @Matias_Cicero, thank you this is definitely the closest answer to what I asked for, However would you say this is likely to be faster or slower then what I have marked as best answer? I marked that one because it allows me to achieve what I need in the neatest way

Comment: @chrispepper1989 This is not even faster than the classic synchronous and sequential way. In fact, I would not use this code for my projects, I'd probably use PLinq as @Yuval recommended. I wrote this because it answers the explicit question on how to achieve synchronization in a `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: Excellent, I feel very much more informed thanks to you and Yuval :)

Comment: @MatiasCicero How can you say this is not faster than the synchronous way without knowing what `GetResultFor()` does and how long does it take?

Answer (score 1):

```
    var nums = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000000);
    var parallel = nums.AsParallel();
    var mapped = parallel.Select(x => (long) unchecked( x * x)); 
    var sum = mapped.Sum();

    Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

The mapping (Select) can always happen in parallel... The reduce (Sum) too "sort of"... you could use many worker threads to sum all the various pairs of sums until you are left with the "last" sum. Usually (90%) summing everything synchronously gives the best result.

---

Another example with select many:

```
        IList<IEnumerable<long>> manyNumbers = new List<IEnumerable<long>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i+=2)
        {
            manyNumbers.Add(Enumerable.Range(2 << i, 2 << (i + 1)).AsParallel().Select(a=> (long)a));
        }
        var parallel = manyNumbers.AsParallel();

        var allPrimes = parallel.SelectMany(sumNums =>
        {
            IEnumerable<long> somePrimes= sumNums.Where(num =>
           {
               for (long i = 2; i <= Math.Sqrt(num); i++)
               {
                   if (num % i == 0)
                   {
                       return false;
                   }
               }
               return true;
           }
            );
            return somePrimes;
        }

        );

        foreach (var number in allPrimes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }

        long sumOfPrimes = allPrimes.Sum();


        Console.WriteLine(sumOfPrimes);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

This isn't a very good algorithm...

Comment: is this in reference to the first block of code then?

Comment: I am sorry I think you misunderstood my post. I dont want a parrallel for that will result in a sum, I was merely posting that as an example of what I have seen before. But I do thank you for bringing to my attention that that block is not actually very good. My main question was how to do more complex functions and add the results to a enumerable